# publish_actions in scope not triggering second dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following javascript code to login to my website using facebook

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
     var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
     //proceed to login
   } else {
     //login failed
   }
 }, {scope: 'publish_actions, email, user_birthday',
     appId  : 'myAppId',
     cookie : true});
```

The first dialog shows up fine requesting their email and birthday. However, the second (optional) dialog does not show up requesting to post to their profile. I have seen this on many sites, but it does not show up on mine.

Is there any other steps I need to take to show this? I have tried publish_stream as well.

EDIT: Still no answer. I am testing with a Facebook account that was previously connected, but I removed the app from my Facebook profile and connected again. That should ensure that the second dialog comes up, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I once read in the facebook documentation you must request this permission in the init function.

try

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'Id_App',
        status: true,
        xfbml: true
    }), { scope: 'publish_actions' };
};